# Appium 1.6.5 - Real iOS Device Execution - Reset Safari (clear history and website data)

Tags: ios, appium

I am trying to start a new session of Safari such that all cache and website data is cleared.

Is there a way to clear cache completely on iOS Safari? Maybe via capabilities for some Appium command?

So far, I have tried noReset, fullReset. Tried setting them both to true and false. Didnt work.

Comment: Can someone please reply to this question?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to set desired capability fullReset to true. -Like this:

```
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", true);
```